# python list strange behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
xlist = []
Xlist = []
for i in range(1):
    xlist.append(x**(i+1))
    Xlist.append(xlist)
xlist.append(x**2)
Xlist.append(xlist)
Xlist
```

However, the output is

```
[[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 4, 9])], [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 4, 9])]]
```

However, I don't know why the result isn't the expression below, and I want the result below, how to achieve that?

```
[[array([1, 2, 3])], [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 4, 9])]]
```

Comment: Are you mixing up append and extend somewhere?

Comment: What is that Xlist at the very end for?

Comment: @LPK He's possibly using a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @QuentinPradet this is so surprising! How can you know that ?!

Comment: @Nishant I hadn't used extend before. I thought "+" is only applicable to strings.

Comment: You are not creating copies, you are just appending the same list object over and over. See the dupe on how to properly copy.

Comment: @PabPeter Because of the "Xlist" at the end which I supposed you used to display Xlist in your notebook. This was the most likely explanation for LPK's question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a copy of the list first then `append` the sqaured array.

```
new_list = xlist+x**(i+1)
xlist.append(new_list)
```

your problem is occuring because `np.array` when appended are passed as reference so if you change it outside the list, the value will change in the list as well.